# Matrix Vector Multiplication should run till target execution time

Tags: c, matrix, vector

My task is to run the matrix vector multiplication c program for like 14-16 minutes. And I am only able that to run for like 20 seconds maximum. I also tried increasing the value of row and columns and also other bunch of stuff and I am not able to do it. Can you please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define NUM_ROWS 600000 // M dimension
#define NUM_COLS 200000// N dimension
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct timeval start, stop, elapse; // declaring the structure elements
gettimeofday( &start, NULL ); // calling gettimeofday function to calculate time
long long int myid, numprocs, i, j;
long long int local_row_sum;
double starttime, endtime;
long long int *matrix = (long long int*)malloc(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS * sizeof(long long int));
long long int *vector = (long long int*)malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(long long int ));
long long int *local_result = (long long int *)malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(long long int));
long long int *final_result = (long long int *)malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(long long int ));

// Initialize array and vector
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
        matrix[i * NUM_COLS + j] = i + j;
    }
}

for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
    vector[j] = j;
}
int k, l;
long long int*sequential_result = (long long int*)malloc(NUM_ROWS * 1 * sizeof(long long int ));

for (k = 0; k < NUM_ROWS; k++)
{
    sequential_result[k] = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < NUM_COLS; l++)
    {
        sequential_result[k] += *(matrix + k * NUM_COLS + l) * *(vector + l);
    }
  printf("The result: %lld\n", sequential_result[k]);
    // Check that sequential result equals MPI result (0 is error code here)
  }
 gettimeofday( &stop, NULL ); // calling gametimeofday function to stop counting the time taken
  timersub( &stop, &start, &elapse ); // calling this function to calculate the time difference
  fprintf( stderr, "Elapse time\t%g\n", elapse.tv_sec+0.000001*elapse.tv_usec );

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the task of "run the program for X minutes".  Are you trying to measure its performance or something?  Either add many more rows/columns or perform your multiplication many times in a loop and output the number of runs after the time limit expires.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a compile error on:

```
long long int *matrix = (long long int *) malloc(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS * sizeof(long long int));
```

The error is:

```
orig.c:21:60: warning: integer overflow in expression of type ‘int’ results in ‘-259084288’ [-Woverflow]
orig.c:21:44: warning: argument 1 value ‘18446744071636877312’ exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]
```

That's because you put the `sizeof` as the *last* term, so it used `int` (32 bits) instead of `size_t` [probably 64 bits].

Thus, the `size` argument actually passed to `malloc` gets wrapped/truncated to 32 bits *before* it is passed as an argument. So, you'll only allocate a much smaller area than you expect.

This probably results in UB (undefined behavior) because the rest of the code will assume the larger area and will modify memory beyond the end of the *actual* allocation.

To fix, do this:

```
long long int *matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
```

This will force the entire argument expression to be 64 bits [which is what you want/need]. You should do similar changes for your other `malloc` calls.

**Edit:** Oops, I missed the fact that your allocation is *so* large that it *can't* be fulfilled by `malloc` [which was flagged by the second error message]. You'll have to cut down the array sizes [see below]

BTW, *don't* cast the return from `malloc`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

And, using the `sizeof(*matrix)` trick is much more likely to produce robust code.

Also, you should *definitely* check the return value from `malloc` for `NULL` and abort if so. You're allocating a *huge* array. Your system may not have enough memory (either *physical* memory or *logical* memory if you've defined swap areas).

Since this check has to be repeated, consider using a wrapper function:

```
void *
safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(size);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"safe_malloc: malloc failure -- size=%zu -- %s\n",
            size,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

And, replace the [fixed/adjusted] `malloc` calls with calls to `safe_malloc`.

I sometimes also use a macro to further reduce repeating boilerplate:

```
#define DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(_typ,_ptr,_count) \
    _typ *_ptr = safe_malloc(sizeof(*_ptr) * (_count))
```

Then, you can do:

```
DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(long long int,matrix,NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> what about `long long int*sequential_result = (long long int*)malloc(NUM_ROWS * 1 * sizeof(long long int ));`

No, I *wouldn't* do that for a few reasons. It *violates* the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle [because you repeated `long long int` *three* times.

Under C, casting the return value of `malloc` which returns a `void *` is *cruft* and can silently mask a bug [if you inadvertently fail to do `#include <stdlib.h>` the compiler will default the return type to `int` and truncate the return value to 32 bits].

Suppose you changed the type of `sequential_result` from `long long int` to (e.g. `long double`). But, didn't change the [bad] cast type or the `sizeof`.

Now, you've got a bug:

```
long double *sequential_result = (long long int *) malloc(sizeof(long long int) * NUM_COLS);
```

Here *not* enough space was allocated.

That's why experienced programmers [usually] prefer the `sizeof(*ptr)`

Further tip: The preferred grouping is:

```
long long int *sequential_result = ...;
```

And, *not*:

```
long long int* sequential_result = ...;
```

That's because if you have:

```
int* a,b;
```

That *seems* to be the equivalent of:

```
int *a;
int *b;
```

But, it is actually:

```
int *a;
int b;
```

The asterisk binds tightly right-to-left and *not* left-to-right. So, doing `int*` is *deceptive*.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Can you please rewrite the program?

Here is the refactored code. I've cut down the dimensions by a factor of 100 to fit into a *sane* amount of memory.

From your question, it seems you want large arrays so you can benchmark for an extended period of time.

I do a lot of code optimization and benchmarking. Smaller size arrays will give you accurate timing data. For a simple matrix multiply, about 10 seconds is sufficient.

I've used `cpp` conditionals to show old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old [broken] code
#else
// new [fixed] code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is the refactored code [as I would write it]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#if 0
#define NUM_ROWS 600000                 // M dimension
#define NUM_COLS 200000                 // N dimension
#else
#define NUM_ROWS 6000                   // M dimension
#define NUM_COLS 2000                   // N dimension
#endif

#define DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(_typ,_ptr,_count) \
    _typ *_ptr = safe_malloc(sizeof(*_ptr) * _count)

typedef long long int bignum_t;

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void *
safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(size);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"safe_malloc: malloc failure -- size=%zu -- %s\n",
            size,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double start, stop;

    start = tscgetf();

    //int myid;
    //int numprocs;
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    //bignum_t local_row_sum;

    DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(bignum_t,matrix,NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
    DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(bignum_t,vector,NUM_COLS);
    DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(bignum_t,local_result,NUM_ROWS);
    DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(bignum_t,final_result,NUM_ROWS);

    bignum_t *mat;

    // Initialize array and vector
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            matrix[i * NUM_COLS + j] = i + j;
        }
    }
#else
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        mat = &matrix[i * NUM_COLS];
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++)
            mat[j] = i + j;
    }
#endif

    for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++)
        vector[j] = j;

    DEFINE_AND_ALLOC_VECTOR(bignum_t,sequential_result,NUM_ROWS);

#if 0
    int k, l;
#else
    size_t k, l;
#endif

#if 0
    for (k = 0; k < NUM_ROWS; k++) {
        sequential_result[k] = 0;
        for (l = 0; l < NUM_COLS; l++) {
            sequential_result[k] += *(matrix + k * NUM_COLS + l) *
                *(vector + l);
        }
    }
#else
    for (k = 0;  k < NUM_ROWS;  ++k) {
        bignum_t acc = 0;
        mat = &matrix[k * NUM_COLS];

        for (l = 0;  l < NUM_COLS;  ++l)
            acc += mat[l] * vector[l];

        sequential_result[k] = acc;
#endif

        printf("The %zu result: %lld\n", k, sequential_result[k]);
        // Check that sequential result equals MPI result (0 is error code here)
    }

    stop = tscgetf();
    fprintf(stderr, "Elapse time\t%.9f seconds\n", stop - start);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about `long long int*sequential_result = (long long int*)malloc(NUM_ROWS * 1 * sizeof(long long int ));`?

Comment: Why the DV??? This is a perfectly reasonable answer. The guidelines are that a good faith answer that is not _egregiously_ wrong should _not_ be DV'ed.

Comment: I did not do that I cannot do that. I am still confused. Can you please rewrite the program?

Comment: I realized that _you_ didn't DV. The comment was for _whomever_ did the "drive by" DVing.

Comment: Este can you please write the code with the changes that you were talking about?

Comment: Just be patient ;-) I'm doing a full cleanup as I would write the code.

Comment: @ Graig Estey were you able to run the program for 14 minutes? Beas=use I think so I don't have to think about efficiency.  Because that is my first target right now